# For loop not printing user input

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Need some expert advice. First here is my code:

```
public static void shapes ( ) {

    System.out.print("Enter the desired width:");
    int  dWidth = CONSOLE.nextInt( );

    for (int k = 0; k<dWidth; k++);
     System.out.print(" __   ");
}
```

My question is: When I enter a user number such as "3" when prompted my code only prints one of the __ when I want it to print the number specified. I can't for the life of me figure it out.

My ultimate goal is to have a program print the following (for a class I'm taking) by a user specified height

```
 __      __      __      __
/    \__/    \__/    \__/    \_
\__/    \__/    \__/    \__/
/    \__/    \__/    \__/    \_
\__/    \__/    \__/    \__/  
/    \__/    \__/    \__/    \_
\__/    \__/    \__/    \__/
```

Sorry it's so sloppy. I am sending this from my phone in a lab because it's due tonight and I'm baffled by the entire thing.

I'm an English major so this is not my forte :(
 The shapes are supposed to be diamonds

Answer (score 2):

You have a ";" at the end of the for line. So it's actually a for loop that does nothing, and print once.

Comment: I feel dumb now. Any advice on how to do the height by user in put?

Comment: One loop in another loop